# Logstash ganglia input plugin - udp listener died

Tags: ruby, plugins, logstash, ganglia

I am using Logstash ganglia input plugin. Ganglia gmond daemon and logstash are installed on same machine. Gmond send metrics to itself. Here is the gmond configuration.

```
udp_send_channel {
  host = 10.0.3.167
  port = 8649
  ttl = 1
}
```

Logstash configuration file is like this :

```
input {
  ganglia {
     host => "127.0.0.1"
     type => "ganglia"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "10.0.3.168"
  }
}
```

While logstash connecting to port which gmond unicasts, I am getting this error:

```
{:timestamp=>"2014-01-04T12:50:38.422000+0000", 
:message=>"ganglia udp listener died", 
:address=>"127.0.0.1:8649", 
:exception=>#<SocketError: bind: name or service not known>, 
:backtrace=>
[
    "org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyUDPSocket.java:160:in `bind'",
    "file:/etc/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/inputs/ganglia.rb:61:in `udp_listener'",
    "file:/etc/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/inputs/ganglia.rb:39:in `run'",
    "file:/etc/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/pipeline.rb:156:in `inputworker'",
    "file:/etc/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/pipeline.rb:150:in `start_input'"
], 
:level=>:warn}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question, hopefully someone do not spend some time to find out this error.
Logstash ganglia input plugin could not connect to port since ganglia monitoring agent (gmond) is running on the same port with logstash. Either u need to redirect gmond to another port or reconfigure ganglia input plugin of logstash.